# Is $\Bbb Z_4 [X]$ an integral domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integral-domain, polynomial-rings

> Is $\Bbb Z_4 [X]$ an integral domain?  Explain why you cannot use the fact that if a commutative ring $R$ is an integral domain, then $R[X]$ is an integral domain.

If $P,Q \in \Bbb Z_4[X]$, then $\Bbb Z_4[X]$ is an integral domain iff $PQ=0 \implies P=0$ or $Q=0$.

How can I verify this here? Should I just consider polynomials in $\Bbb Z_4 [X]$ and check cases?

Comment: Your summary is incorrect; the quantification is in the wrong order. It should be that "$\mathbb{Z}_4$ is an interal domain if and only if (for all $P,Q\in\mathbb{Z}_4[X]$, $PQ=0\implies P=0$ or $Q=0$)". That assumes you already know it is a commutative ring with $1\neq 0$, of course, so that the only remaining thing left to check is whether it has nontrivial zero divisors.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_4$ isn't even an integral domain: $2\cdot 2 = 0.$

Comment: Apparently this fact cannot be used here.

Comment: Why not? If $R[x]$ is an integral domain then $R$ is clearly an integral domain as well, as it is a subring. (up to isomorphism)

Comment: @RicoJello there are two different things going on here. in general, for a ring $R$, we have that $R$ is an integral domain if and only if $R[X]$ is an integral domain. your question asks you to explain why you cannot employ the "only if" direction of this fact to prove the desired result. on the other hand, you *can* exmploy the "if" direction to prove the result, and this is what Michael's answer and Mark's comment exploit